# Anime with a little red haired character who pilots a racing pod

Tags: oban-star-racers

My son is looking for an anime. He says its main character is a little red-haired girl who pilots a racing pod. The pod has two large guns on each side. She uses this pod in a race of some kind. The organizer of the race fools the girl into thinking there is a prize but there isn't one. He also thinks the girls has something that looks like 2 band-aides on each side of her mouth.

I know this seems vague, but any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does this has to do with the [tag:characters] tag?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would wager that he's looking for [*Ōban Star-Racers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%8Cban_Star-Racers). It's a series, but was based on a short movie called *Molly Star Racer*.

The basic story starts as:

> In the year 2082, Earth has been invited to compete in the Great Race of Ōban, an intergalactic race whose winner can be granted any wish in the world — even bringing back a loved one.
>
> -- Wikipedia

Additionally, the marks on the main character's face (a female) resemble band-aids (though one's a star):

[image]

Comment: OMG! You are my savior. If could vote your answer 10 times I would! Thank you!

Comment: Omg thanks sooo much I have been trying to finds this for hours and I finally I can watch it. thank you again