# Anime involving aliens racing?

Tags: oban-star-racers

I remember seeing this on TV as a younger kid but I don't know what it's called. I think Adult Swim was where I saw it.
This girl runs off and joins this team that's in a race with a bunch of other alien species. Her dad is the leader but he doesn't know the girl is his daughter. Her mother was a pilot and she died in a race so the dad didn't want the daughter to race. There's an alien that has a white mask and shadow powers sorta. People think it killed her mother, bit it tried to help her before the ship exploded.
there's like this mother ship like thing that's the 'garages' are on and it moves to right above the next race start and then the racers drop from the ship.

Thank you in advance for any help given.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anime with a little red haired character who pilots a racing pod](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/809/anime-with-a-little-red-haired-character-who-pilots-a-racing-pod)

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like [Oban Star Racers](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1212/Oban_Star-Racers).

[image]

Here are a few quotes comfirming that from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%8Cban_Star-Racers):

> Unable to tell her father who she really is, she lands a job as a mechanic in his team under the name "Molly"
>
> Haunted by the death of her mother — a famous star-racer — and the harsh "reunion" with her father, Molly is determined to win so she can be with her parents once again.

And here's the opening sequence:

http://youtu.be/TIKQBNlwhHA

Comment: If this is indeed it, I believe it is a dup of this question here then > http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/809/anime-with-a-little-red-haired-character-who-pilots-a-racing-pod

Comment: ID requests can't be dupes, they're all different and we should not assume they are the same. There can be several works that may fit the same description and different sets of works for different descriptions.

Comment: @user1306322- Actually image ones can be, but if the owner does accept this as the answer (highly unlikely since most new users only show up once and rarely return) than it could be a dupe but if he doesn't return and accept your answer then I guess we wouldn't know so I guess I should probably maybe reconsider my voting as the question being a dupe.

Comment: They are related, sure, but not duplicate as far as only textual description is given. Image ID requests though may be dupes.